# KeyError: 'type' while drawing a scatter plot with grouped x axis in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to draw a scatter plot with x and y axis with x axes grouped. x axis will be three types(e.g. h, o, c), which is identifiable by ID column. y axis will have mean values per each ID.

Here's sample data:

```
       id   sum       mean    color  type
0     109  2852    5.301115     r      h
1     110  3162    5.877323     r      h
2     111  1997    3.711896     b      o
```

Y axis will be "mean" column value and X axis will be grouped "id" value. When I run my code below, it generates an error:

```
 File "pandas\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4279)
 File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 732, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:13742)
 File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 740, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:13696)
 KeyError: 'type'
```

Here'e my code:

```
df.set_index('type', inplace=True)
...
col = df['type'].map({'h':'r', 'o':'b', 'c':'y'})
ax = df.plot.scatter(x='type', y='mean', c=col)
```

Comment: Which line is it failing on?

Comment: @bendl this line, `ax = df.plot.scatter(x='type', y='mean', c=col)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the x-axis of your scatter plot needs to by a numeric value.
You can bypass this by creating a numeric id for your values and map them back to the plot with labels

```
df['type'] = df['type'].astype('category')
df['type_id'] = df.type.cat.codes
plt.scatter(x=df['type_id'], y=df['mean'], color=df['color'])
plt.xticks(df['type_id'].tolist(), df['type'], rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]